# Создание многоуровневого меню на Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как сделать на wordpress многоуровневое меню?
 Допустим есть такой массив объектов:

```
$categories = get_categories( 'taxonomy=product_cat' );
```

Как теперь построить другой массив, чтобы если в поле category_parent не нулевое значение, тогда вложить эту подкатегорию в категорию-родитель?
Пытался сделать так:

```
$categoriesObj = get_categories( 'taxonomy=product_cat' );
$categories = array();
foreach ($categoriesObj as $cat) {
    $categories[] = (array)$cat;
}
$tree = [];
foreach ($categories as &$category) {
    if (!$category['category_parent'])
        $tree[$category['term_id']] = &$category;
    else{
        $categories[$category['category_parent']]['childs'][$category['term_id']] = &$category;
    }
}
```

но выдаёт ошибку "Undefined index: category_parent"
И желательно показать, как сделать цикл, в котором для категорий и подкатегорий задаются разные блоки при формировании html меню

Comment: рекурсия рекурсия....

Comment: @Naumov
А пример показать можете?

Comment: что в get_categories

Comment: Возвращает массив объектов содержащих информацию о категориях.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_categories

Comment: Или как привести вышеприведённый код к рабочему состоянию?

Comment: У кого какие идеи?

Comment: у вас амперсанд перед `$category` то появляется, то исчезает. Что это за хитрая магия?

Comment: @alenkins предложите свой вариант

Comment: это не магия, массив передается по ссылке, чтобы можно было его менять в цикле

Comment: что посоветуете?

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как сделал нужное меню, но есть одна ошибка.
Вообщем меню создаётся нормально, но вместо самой последней подкатегории выводится почему-то родительская категория этой подкатегории.

```
$categoriesObj = get_categories( 'taxonomy=product_cat' );
$categories = array();
foreach ($categoriesObj as $cat) {
    $categories[$cat->cat_ID] = (array)$cat;
}

$treeMenu = array();
foreach ($categories as $id => &$category) {
    if (!$category['category_parent'])
        $treeMenu[$id] = &$category;
    else{
        $categories[$category['category_parent']]['childs'][$category['cat_ID']] = &$category;
    }
}
foreach ( $treeMenu as $category ) {
    echo 'category_nicename='.$category['category_nicename'].'<br>';
    echo 'cat_name='.$category['cat_name'].'<br>';
    if (isset($category['childs'])) {
        $tab = '----';
        foreach ( $category['childs'] as $cat ) {

            echo $tab.'category_nicename='.$cat['category_nicename'].'<br>';
            echo $tab.'cat_name='.$cat['cat_name'].'<br>';

        }
    }
}
```

Если в последнем цикле сделать var_export($category), то выдаёт такую ошибку перед выводом самой последней подкатегории:

```
var_export does not handle circular references in
```

Подскажите, как устранить эту ошибку? т.е. чтобы вместо последней подкатегории выводилась не родительская категория

```
category1
--subcat1
--subcat2
category2
--subcat1
--subcat2
--category2
```

Comment: люди, как это исправить?

Comment: или как нужно делать правильно многоуровневое меню?